# How to add frequency of different letters for different positions across words in a list?

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures

> I need to find the frequency of the elements in "letters" list in the
> words given in list "a"   a = ['ram', 'rah', 'arj'] letters = ['r',
> 'm'] the expected answer here is :  for letter r : [2,1,0]  the
> frequency across the three words is where 2 denotes the  frequency of
> letter r in the 1st place, 1 denotes the frequency  in the middle
> position and 0 the frequency for the last position Similarly for
> letter m : [0, 0, 1] I am unable to write the code for this task.
> Please help. using the below code, I am getting list out of index error.

```
a = ['ram', 'rah', 'arj']
b = ['r', 'a', 'm']
for s in b:
    s3 = {}
    s2 = []
    s3[i] = s2 
    for i in a:
        s1 = []
        for j in range(len(i)):
            if s == i[j]:
                s1.append(1)
                s2.append(s2[j] + s1[j])
```

Comment: What have you done to debug your code? What is the first statement where things go wrong? What is `remain_letters`? What is `self`? What is `current_dicitonary`?

Comment: why is the frequency of letter a is 2 in `ram`, 1 in `rah` and 0 in `arj` while all of them have 1 a?

Comment: @NavidNaseri the frequency of each letter is counted across the words. r occurs as the first letter for the 1st two words and in 2nd position for the third word.

Comment: @trincot I am getting list index out of range error with my code

Comment: Please edit your question so we know that your question is about that error, and indicate in which line in occurs and what you have done to debug that situation. When I run your code I get `name 'i' is not defined.` Not the error you mention.

Answer (score 1):

You can do what you want very easily with `zip`, as long as all words are the exact same length.

```py
L = ['ram', 'rah', 'arj']

def freq(data, char):
    return list(t.count(char) for t in zip(*data))

print(freq(L, 'r')) #[2, 1, 0]
print(freq(L, 'm')) #[0, 0, 1]
print(freq(L, 'a')) #[1, 2, 0]
```

`zip` is giving us all of the first characters, then all of the second characters, etc... Once we have that working for us, we can simply count how many times the desired letter appears in that iteration, and store it. If your words are not of equal length this will not work, as-is.

It would be trivial to go over every word and reformat them to the proper length, though.

```py
L = ['ram', 'rah', 'arji']

def freq(data, char):
    mw = max(len(w) for w in data)    #get max length

    #format all words to max length by adding spaces to the end
    dt = [f'{w:<{mw}}' for w in data] 

    return list(t.count(char) for t in zip(*dt))

print(freq(L, 'i')) #[0, 0, 0, 1]
```

Comment: @Rahul - According to your profile, you have never accepted any of the answers you were given. Is there some reason why you don't have to do your part? Is the gigantic check mark to the left of all your answers not big enough? You're supposed to accept one answer per question, if there is an answer that solves your problem. Failing to do so, just hurts you. I'm not the only one checking your profile to see if you accept answers. Eventually you wont get any answers. Certainly not good ones.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a naive answer:

First, find the maximum length of words i.e. number of positions:

```py
num_positions = max(len(i) for i in words)
```

create a list for saving the result:

```py
result = [[0 for _ in range(num_positions)] for _ in range(len(letters))]
```

iterate over letters to calculate the result for them:

```py
for i, l in enumerate(letters):
    for j in range(num_positions):
        result[i][j] = sum(1 for w in words if len(w) > j and w[j] == l)

print(result)
```

---

Here is the final(runnable) code:

```py
words = ['ram', 'rah', 'arj', 'longer']
letters = ['r', 'a', 'j', 'g']

num_positions = max(len(i) for i in words)
result = [[0 for _ in range(num_positions)] for _ in range(len(letters))]

for i, l in enumerate(letters):
    for j in range(num_positions):
        result[i][j] = sum(1 for w in words if len(w) > j and w[j] == l)

print(result)
```

and with list comprehension:

```py
words = ['ram', 'rah', 'arj', 'longer']
letters = ['r', 'a', 'j', 'g']

num_positions = max(len(i) for i in words)
result = [
    [sum(1 for w in words if len(w) > j and w[j] == l)
        for j in range(num_positions)
    ] for i, l in enumerate(letters)
]


print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

First build a dictionary with the letters to be counted as keys and prepared list of zero counts for each position.  Then go through you words (list a) and enumerate their letters.  This will give you pairs of positions and letters.  Add 1 to the dictionary's counter for letters that are counted at the count position that matches the letter's position:

```
a = ['ram', 'rah', 'arj']
b = ['r', 'a', 'm']

maxLen = 3 # max(map(len,a))           # longest word = number of counts
counts = {c:[0]*maxLen for c in b}     # prepare counters lists
for word in a:                         # loop through words
    for pos,letter in enumerate(word): # enumerate letters of each word
        if letter in counts:           # if letter needs to be counted,
            counts[letter][pos] += 1   # increase corresponding count
```

output:

```
print(counts)
{'r': [2, 1, 0], 'a': [1, 2, 0], 'm': [0, 0, 1]}
```

A more concise (albeit less efficient) approach would be to use a list comprehension with a dictionary comprehension:

```
counts = { c:[ sum(c==w[i:i+1] for w in a) for i in range(3)] for c in b }

 print(counts)
{'r': [2, 1, 0], 'a': [1, 2, 0], 'm': [0, 0, 1]}
```